# How do I show data count in real time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

oops I was thinking something when a question was asked...ok I do have near about 200000 datas in my MySQL database and counting.

so what I want is to show that number in real time or say within some interval...

for example the current status is 2000000
after, let's say, 5 hours it may be 2000156

Comment: What do you mean by "data count?"  When you say "real time" do you mean the count should continuously update on the page?

Comment: Award for most vague question of the year goes to...

Comment: Please clarify what you see as real time and what you will want to be getting from db and type

Comment: in terms of "real time" i assume you want to avoid having to refresh the page? Use AJAX then...

Comment: Do you mean something like displaying the number of rows in a table every few seconds on a site? If so, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table will give you the count. Doing the query from php is just like any other query. To get it to "update in real time" (it won't) you'll probably have a javascript executing the query (via php) every n seconds.

Comment: You can pull out information say every 5 mins or so by making an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [mysql count()](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php) function

Answer (score 0):

Yep as pervious answer you can use the mysql count() function, usage is as such:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE condition='value';
```

I wouldn't advise using this frequently, if all it does is return a count of the tuples in your database.

Infrequent use should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

in case you mean the row count of a table.

in your html (or php) page write this somewhere between your head tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> // you don't have to write this line if you already included jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function updateDataCount(){
      $('#datacount').load('getDataCount.php');
    }
    updateDataCount(); //set the datacount as soon as the page is loaded
    setInterval( "updateDataCount()", 10000 ); //update the datacount every 10 seconds
  });
</script>
```

Then create an element on your page, where you want to display your datacount in:

```
<div id = "datacount"></div>
```

Finaly you need to create the file getDataCount.php which will look like this:

```
<?php
  //put your logic here to connect to your database

  $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM [your table]";      
  $numrows = mysql_result($query, "0");
  print $numrows;
?>
```

Comment: Please don't ever develop a website for my company, `SELECT *` and `mysql_num_rows` to count the rows in a table? Do you not know what `COUNT(*)` is?

Answer (score 0):

What Engine do you use MyISAM or InnoDb? Do you really nean get count in real time or you could get data a little bit obsolete?
I think using Count all the can be very expensive if you use InnoDb engine. For example, MyISAM engine always stores the number of columns, so Count query is very fast.